# new pandas apply 'float' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a df with a Date column as a MM-DD-YYYY string.  I'd like to convert it to a YYYY/MM/DD string.  I tried the following:

```
def date_MDY_YMD(s):
    """Convert string date from MM/DD/YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD."""
    M = s[:2]
    D = s[3:5]
    Y = s[6:10]
    return '-'.join((Y, M, D))

df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(date_MDY_YMD)
```

I get the error "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable"
'float' confuses me: df.dtypes tells me Date is an object, but all the examples I've looked at are strings.

There are similar questions on stackoverflow, but they focus speed problems from using apply() on a column or needing to get at multiple columns.  Neither is a difficulty here.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sample input is essential if you want to have a chance of someone answering this question. For obvious reasons.

Comment: Sounds like there could be nulls in your data. But as @timgeb is saying, sample data is king.

Comment: Try to add `if pd.isna(s): return s` in the beginning of your function. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71398181/16343464) for better alternatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, I do not reproduce your issue with the following input.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['08-03-2022', '31-12-2022']})
```

You probably have NaNs as this input triggers the error:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['08-03-2022', '31-12-2022', float('nan')]})
```

That said, do not use `apply`, it is slow. Take advantage of pandas vector functions (you also won't have issues with missing values).

Using [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True).dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
```

Using string replacement with [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and a regex:

```
df['Date3'] = df['Date'].str.replace(r'(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})', r'\3/\2/\1',
                                     regex=True)
```

output:

```
         Date       Date2       Date3
0  08-03-2022  2022/03/08  2022/03/08
1  31-12-2022  2022/12/31  2022/12/31
2         NaN         NaN         NaN
```